# Test a package "zbar" in root

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

how to test a package if that package is available in a linux IMX6UL board.
these are the packages.
libzbar.so.0.2.0
libzbar.so.0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (A big assumption) you're OS on IMX6UL is Debian, you can:

```bash
$ apt update
$ apt-cache search libzbar
libzbar-dev - bar code scanner and decoder (development)
libzbar0 - bar code scanner and decoder (library)
libzbargtk-dev - bar code scanner and decoder (GTK+ bindings development)
libzbargtk0 - bar code scanner and decoder (GTK+ bindings)
libzbarqt-dev - bar code scanner and decoder (Qt bindings development)
libzbarqt0 - bar code scanner and decoder (Qt bindings)
```

You can also search online at https://packages.debian.org/index

Pay attention to the architecture for some packages as not all will be available for your architecture.

[image: Debian Packages Search]

Comment: Thank you Brian .. can we test a library without having the binaries in the board?

Comment: Yes, you can search online. I edited the answer.